# Mysql inner join with where

Tags: mysql, optimization, explain

```
    SELECT pm.team,
       pm.username,
       count(DISTINCT if(offer_pm.revenue>0.0,adv.adv_name,NULL)) AS adv_count,
       sum(offer_pm.click),
       sum(offer_pm.install),
       sum(offer_pm.revenue),
       sum(offer_pm.cost)
FROM (pm pm
      INNER JOIN offer_pm_adv_day offer_pm ON offer_pm.pm_id=pm.id)
INNER JOIN advertiser adv ON offer_pm.adv_id=adv.id
WHERE offer_pm.logdate>='2016-01-01'
    AND offer_pm.logdate<='2017-01-01'
GROUP BY pm.team,
         pm.username
```

If  there is a where condition  `offer_pm.logdate>='2016-01-01' and offer_pm.logdate<='2017-01-01'`
below is the explain for the sql . And the cost time is long (20s)

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: offer_pm
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,adv_id_index,logdate_index
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 3
          ref: NULL
         rows: 713003
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    -->Useing where 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pm
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,uniq_name_team
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: summary_report_refactor2.offer_pm.pm_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where    

*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: adv
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: summary_report_refactor2.offer_pm.adv_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

But  the sql

```
SELECT pm.team,
       pm.username,
       count(DISTINCT if(offer_pm.revenue>0.0,adv.adv_name,NULL)) AS adv_count,
       sum(offer_pm.click),
       sum(offer_pm.install),
       sum(offer_pm.revenue),
       sum(offer_pm.cost)
FROM (pm pm
      INNER JOIN offer_pm_adv_day offer_pm ON offer_pm.pm_id=pm.id)
INNER JOIN advertiser adv ON offer_pm.adv_id=adv.id
GROUP BY pm.team,
         pm.username
```

which do not with where condition.

The cost time is 2s  . The explain is

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pm
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY,uniq_name_team
          key: uniq_name_team
      key_len: 604
          ref: NULL
         rows: 91
        Extra: Using index; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: offer_pm
         type: ref
possible_keys: adv_id_index,pm_id_index
          key: pm_id_index
      key_len: 4
          ref: summary_report_refactor2.pm.id
         rows: 10042
        Extra: Using index condition
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: adv
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: summary_report_refactor2.offer_pm.adv_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

BTW, there is an index on logdate column.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what type of attribute is the logdate column?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.

Comment: Did you really want to include two Jan 1 dates?

Comment: This may be the classic "explode-implode" problem of `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`.  Note that you had to do `DISTINCT` to avoid it for the `COUNT`.  Did the `SUMs` come out too big?  Is the mapping 1:many; if so, which way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on the logdate, try this query:

```
SELECT straight_join pm.team,
       pm.username,
       count(DISTINCT if(offer_pm.revenue>0.0,adv.adv_name,NULL)) AS adv_count,
       sum(offer_pm.click),
       sum(offer_pm.install),
       sum(offer_pm.revenue),
       sum(offer_pm.cost)
FROM offer_pm_adv_day offer_pm
INNER JOIN pm ON offer_pm.pm_id=pm.id
INNER JOIN advertiser adv ON offer_pm.adv_id=adv.id
WHERE offer_pm.logdate>='2016-01-01'
    AND offer_pm.logdate<='2017-01-01'
GROUP BY pm.team,
         pm.username ;
```

It basically has to do with the way your tables are organized. 
And what keys the execution planner is using.

By using `straight_join` you can force a certain way of joining the tables and sometimes improve the execution time a bit.
You can also look at mysql `force key` or `force index` options.

Or you can modify the way you're joining your tables:

```
SELECT pm.team,
       pm.username,
       count(DISTINCT if(offer_pm.revenue>0.0,adv.adv_name,NULL)) AS adv_count,
       sum(offer_pm.click),
       sum(offer_pm.install),
       sum(offer_pm.revenue),
       sum(offer_pm.cost)
FROM pm
INNER JOIN offer_pm_adv_day offer_pm ON offer_pm.pm_id=pm.id
    AND offer_pm.logdate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'
INNER JOIN advertiser adv ON offer_pm.adv_id=adv.id
GROUP BY pm.team,
         pm.username
```